# Bash script error in my computer but NOT on some others

Tags: bash

the script:

```
waktu=$(date +"%H")
kelompok="E20"
dir_skrg=$(pwd)

if (( $waktu >= 5 && $waktu <= 10 ))
then
    salam="pagi"
elif (( $waktu >= 10 && $waktu <= 3 ))
then
    salam="siang"
elif (( $waktu >= 4 && $waktu <= 7 ))
then
    salam="sore"
else 
    salam="malam"
fi

echo “Selamat $salam $kelompok dengan user $USER, sekarang pukul $waktu dan pada direktori $dir_skrg”
```

it gives error:

```
script1.sh: 5: script1.sh: 14: not found
script1.sh: 8: script1.sh: 14: not found
script1.sh: 11: script1.sh: 14: not found
```

but not in my friend ubuntu's. andybody knows why?

14 is the hour when I run the script, I assume for some reason it thinks 14 is a file

Comment: is this the whole file? It's obviously complaining about lines 5,8, and 11. Just wanted to make sure those are the actual lines.

Comment: yeah it is the whole file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like that is being run as a shell (sh) script rather than bash script. Try to run it like this:

```
bash script.sh
```

or enter the following as the first line of your script

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Then run as `./script.sh`

Comment: ah yeah silly mistakes after all. I thought it is the same. Thanks :D

Comment: For many practical purposes, it is the same. However, bash is way richer than sh alone; for example, in sh, you would write `\`command\`` rather than $(command), or `if [ $n1 -gt $n2 ] ; then` rather than `if (( $n1 > $n2 )) ; then`.

Answer (score 5):

Add `#!/bin/bash` to the top of your script, as the first line.

> **Note:** This is called a shebang. More information about it may be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29).

Give your script the correct permissions.

```
chmod a+x <script_name>
```

Run your script again.

```
./<script_name>
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but my script still don't works

Comment: @HaidarM. Then **edit your question** to give the exact errors you encounter, if they've changed.

Comment: it works actually, sorry, my mistakes :D

Comment: @HaidarM. Great! Please consider **upvoting** all the useful answers. This encourages people to help you in the future. Thank you! :)